# How to remove Spacing from google's Material Design Icons Exterior?

Tags: html, css, material-design, font-awesome, reset

**Headnote:** I am having trouble removing spacing from around [Google's Material Design icons](https://material.io/), and cannot seem to find any solutions on Google or [the Material Design icons guide](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/). I am not sure whether the answer is blatantly simple and I'm missing it, or whether there is a more profound reason as to why I am unable to accomplish a seemingly simple task.

Below you can find extracts from the relevant code in my project, or, alternatively, you can [view my full project here](https://github.com/NeocryptNetwork/neocryptnetwork.github.io).

- My markup,

  ```
  <header class="primary-header first-header-column">
    <i class="material-icons primary-header-material-icon-first-menu">
      menu
    </i>
    <h1>
      <strong>
        Neocrypt
      </strong> 
      Network
    </h1>
    <nav class="primary-header-navigation">

    </nav>
  </header>
  ```
- the icon styling,

  ```
  .material-icons.primary-header-material-icon-first-menu {
    color: var(--primary-typeface-color);
    font-size: 48px;
  }
  ```
- the heading styling, and

  ```
  .primary-header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--primary-typeface-color);
    display: inline;
    font-family: var(--primary-typeface);
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 150px;
  }
  ```
- the referenced variables (unrelated).

  ```
  :root {
    --primary-typeface-color: #ffffff;
    --primary-typeface: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  ```

I would like the icon to appear directly beside the heading with no padding around the icon so that I can add spacing around the elements myself, almost like a reset! I've tried using `padding: 0px;`, in addition to a few other solutions to try and resolve the issue, however, it was to no avail.

**Footnote:** I am using [Eric Meyer's "Reset CSS"](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset), however, to my knowledge, this should have no effect on Google's Material Design icons.

---

**Update (24/03/2018 01:33 UTC):** It seems as though Google adds spacing around the icon in the image file itself, giving users no option to format said spacing. If anyone else has this same problem, I would recommend that you use another icon font, such as [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

Comment: The `<h1>` element is displayed inline, though, @Laslos. There is no whitespace between the`<h1>` element and the `<i>` that is created by the `<h1>` element; only by the `<i>` element itself.

Comment: I missed that in your CSS - your markup doesn't define the class on the `<h1>`, so your inline display attribute for the `<h1>` isn't applied.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. I am not sure then, I would guess the material design icon has spacing in the image file.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case. I'll just have to put up with it until someone finds a solution then, or perhaps it's time to switch to Font Awesome, haha. Thanks for your time, @Laslos.

Comment: I wonder what the reasoning is behind this padding in the icon files? It's a mistake I see junior designers make, but seeing as Google does it, there must be some justification?

Comment: The spacing is to provide enough visual difference between an icon and the content surrounding it. All the icons are on a 24x24 grid with most icons sitting inside the 20x20 inner section. Some icons may stray into the surrounding space when extra space is needed. See the [guidelines](https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html) for more info.

Comment: @JamesCoyle I understand the principle but the fact is that when we include these icons inside a button it's always incorrect because of that extra padding. Did anyone came up with a fix or patch for this? In my case I'm using the SVG through a content url

Answer (score 3):

what I did was wrapping the `icon` with a `span` and give it a fix `hight` and `width` then all I had to do was to hide the `overflow` .

That's how it looks in my browser.
[image: result]

An example for removing the white space from the icon.

```css
.print-element {
  min-width: 175px;
  min-height: 45px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 25px 25px 15px 0px;
  cursor: move;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
  transition: box-shadow 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.resize-circle {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  border: .1px solid white;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: -7px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="print-element">
  Tag Number
  <span><i class="material-icons resize-circle">highlight_off</i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This was clever. Thanks. `width` , `height` , `overflow: hidden;` and for me `line-height` equal to `height`, beat the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled this problem by applying a **negative margin**. It works... but the way Font Awesome solved this is awesome, totally agree with @Michael Burns.

When applying the negative margin, the px will depend on the icon size and the specific icon. But at least it is still consistent in different browsers.

```css
.material-icons.primary-header-material-icon-first-menu {
  margin-left: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the padding manually is not a scalable solution, so I just created a tool to remove the padding from all the icons in the set. It does require you to create a new icon set, but it might be helpful:
https://github.com/jgillick/IconsetCropper